# Existence of function $\phi(x,y)$ given that $(1+u_y^2)u_{xx} - 2u_xu_yu_{xy}+(1+u_x^2)u_{yy}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

On [this paper](https://maths.anu.edu.au/files/CMAProcVol34P2-Athanassenas.pdf) by M. Athanassenas it is claimed that given a function $u(x,y)$ defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it satisfies
$$
(1+u_y^2)u_{xx} - 2u_xu_yu_{xy}+(1+u_x^2)u_{yy} = 0
$$
If and only if there exists a function $\phi(x,y)$ such that
\begin{align}
\phi_{xx} = \frac{1+u_x^2}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2+u_y^2}} \\
\phi_{xy} = \frac{u_xu_y}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2+u_y^2}} \\
\phi_{yy} = \frac{1+u_y^2}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2+u_y^2}}
\end{align}
I do not see why this would be but I suspect that it has something to do with a Taylor expansion. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: As per @Bob_Terrell 's suggestion I have fixed the equation presented (the minimal surface equation)

Comment: @Narasimham I'm sorry it's meant to be equal to $0$

Comment: Athanassenas refers to this method of proof as being due to Nitsche 1956. The paper is just two pages long and is available on [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969907). There's a bit of translation going on between Nitsche's paper and Athanassenas's presentation, though, so I'm not sure how much the original will actually clarify matters.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have $1+u_x^2$ and $1+u_y^2$ interchanged in the minimal surface equation, because it is misprinted in the paper you cite. 
Second, just a suggestion, since in two dimensions a divergence can be interpreted as a curl, the integral
$$\int_{(0,0)}^{(x,y)}\frac{-u_y dx+u_x dy}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2+u_y^2}}$$
defines a function (is independent of path). That might be what is intended by $\phi$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: How do you know this integral is independent of path?

Comment: Because the minimal surface equation is $(u_x/\sqrt(1+u_x^2+u_y^2})_x+(u_y/\sqrt{1+u_x^2+u_y^2})_y = 0$.

Comment: Oh right of course. So we have that the field $(-u_y, u_x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2+u_y^2}}$ is conservative. Now how would one go about differentiating? Ie, finding $\phi_{xx}$, etc.

Comment: When an integral is independent of path, you can use a path from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ that ends with a short segment parallel to the $x$ axis, On that segment $dy = 0$, so the $x$ partial derivative is just the coefficient of $dx$, by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus. Similarly use a path ending with a vertical segment to show that the $y$ partial derivative is the coefficient of $dy$. That will give you $\phi_x$ and $\phi_y$. From there you can get second derivatives, but I did not succeed in showing that they have the stated properties.

Comment: Are you saying that $\phi_x = \frac{-u_y}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2+u_y^2}}$?

Comment: Yes, if this integral is a good choice for $\phi$.

Comment: Hello! Sadly this integral did not do the trick. It was easy to find the second partials $\phi_{xx}, \phi_{xy}, \phi_{yx}, \phi_{yy}$. With the minimal surface equation it is easily proven that $\phi_{xy} = \phi_{yx}$. Now, with the $phi$ given in the article it is known that $\phi_{xx}\phi_{yy} -\phi_{xy}^2 = 1$. But with the $\phi$ suggested here we had that $\phi_{xx}\phi_{yy}-\phi_{xy}^2 = \phi_{xx}\phi_{yy}-\phi_{xy}\phi_{yx} \neq 1$. So the suggested $\phi$ and the given $\phi$ cannot be the same :(